# Can't get NODE_ENV to stick on my MEAN stack on open shift

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have:

- added **export NODE_ENV=production** to app-root/data/.bashprofile (and echo $NODE_ENV shows production)
- Tried **rhc set-env NODE_ENV=production -a myapp** which generates **Setting environment variable(s) ... Server returned an unexpected error code: 501**
- Created an .openshift/action_hooks directory in my local repo and added the line export NODE_ENV=production to both a start and a pre_start file, committed and pushed to openshift
- Tried the .openshift/action_hooks/pre_start_* aswell
- Declared a root variable (as tipsed by @JuJoDi below) in the beginning of my **server.js** file, now it looks lite this:

  ```
  var express = require('express'),
   routes = require('./routes'),
   api = require('./routes/api'),
   http = require('http'), 
   path = require('path'),
   everyauth = require('everyauth'), 
   connect = require('connect'),
   env = process.env.NODE_ENV ? process.env.NODE_ENV : "process.env.NODE_ENV is null";
  ```

I'm then printing out using this route:

```
app.get('/version', function(req,res){
        res.json({
            "app.get('env')" : app.get('env'),
            "process.env.NODE_ENV" : process.env.NODE_ENV,
                            "Global env" : env
        });
    });
```

What happens is that app.get('env') always returns 'development' and process.env.NODE_ENV is not printed at all (null value)

Has anyone got any ideas why this isn't working?

### UPDATE

I created a minimalistic node server, still can't get any env-variables to work on open shift:

```
    var http = require('http');

    var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000;
    var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || process.env.OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP || 'localhost';
    var env = process.env.NODE_ENV

    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.end('' + process.env.NODE_ENV + "|" + env);
    }).listen(port, ipaddress);
```

Comment: what happens if you start your server with `NODE_ENV=production node server.js`

Comment: it works great. But I believe I can't do that on openshift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce this issue.  I think the **501 error** response that you initially received is the cause of your problems.

You should be able to troubleshoot by running the following from within in your project source folder (add `-a YOUR_APP_NAME` to the end of each command to run elsewhere):

1. Check your current list of application tokens:

   rhc env list
2. If you have something listed for `NODE_ENV`, then clear it:

   rhc unset NODE_ENV
3. Set your `NODE_ENV` to "production":

   rhc env set NODE_ENV="production"
4. Verify that the value has been set by reloading your server, by running `rhc env list`, or by connecting to your application over SSH to check the system environment directly:

   rhc ssh

   env | grep NODE_ENV

Running `rhc help env` provides a lot of good usage info as well.  Depending on how they're written, some servers need to be reloaded in order to fetch the new content.

I think the easiest way to get up and running with MEANStack on OpenShift is to use [Yeoman's Angular-fullstack generator](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack#heroku--openshift). It should automatically configure your environment for you.

Comment: Happy to help troubleshoot in #OpenShift on FreeNode IRC as well

Comment: Well, today when I revisit this issue and followed your example it worked very well. I don't know if I have changed anything or if something has happened on openshift. However, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

That closure does not have access to the process object.  Above that try

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
```

then print it with

```
app.get('/version', function(req,res){
        res.json({
            "app.get('env')" : app.get('env'),
            "process.env.NODE_ENV" : env
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I tried out your idea but it still don't work. On my local node.js server the closure has access to the process even in that scope.

Comment: Interesting, I just tested it on mine and it definitely does not.  It's a `var self = this` situation.  What version of node are you running?

Comment: I'm running node.js v0.10.12

Answer (score 0):

When you run the app, try this:

```
NODE_ENV=production npm start
```

Substitute `npm start` with whatever way you start your app (`node server` or whatever).

That's the way I change the environment, when I am working locally. Since I usually want it to be `development`.

Express.js will default `app.get('env')` to `development` if `process.env.NODE_ENV` isn't set.

Update:

Sorry, missed the OpenShift part :/

https://www.openshift.com/developers/openshift-environment-variables

Looks like the environment variables in OpenShift need to go in:

.openshift/action_hooks/build

Using `export`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thank you Johnny, that works great on my local machine. Actually I have no problems locally just with the OpenShift environment. I simply can't get any custom environmental variables to work when deploying on openshift.